# How to plot lack of data in bar plot?

Tags: visualization

I have the following bar plot showing retrieval precision for specific documents:

[image]

First *n* documents have no specific precision because retrieval returned no data for them. This is ambiguous because no bar can mean either 0 value or lack of data.

How can I make it clear in a bar plot?

Some ideas:

- render specific values close to the bar
- `fillna(-1)` and render negative values in red

Any other?

Here's Panda series I am trying to render:

```
9881449     0.375
22860031    0.625
18222644    1.000
5708161       NaN
10021344      NaN
10021491      NaN
10021595      NaN
10021614      NaN
10021709      NaN
10022498      NaN
10023240      NaN
10023252      NaN
10023458      NaN
10023706      NaN
22239796      NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Couldn't you do one bar plot for positive documents and just list the negative ones separately?

Comment: @PiotrRarus-ReinstateMonica Sounds good. Simplest solutions are the best. Thanks.